# How to add a class to ul tags created by the WordPress editor Tinymce?

Tags: css, tinymce, editor

I want to set a special styling for the ul tags created by Tinymce only, which means only for posts and pages, I only found this filter [tiny_mce_before_init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init) with an example on how to add custom style options to an existing style dropdown.

so is there a way to add a class to ul tags created by the WordPress editor ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's always a good idea to look at Wordpress Codex before asking. [TinyMCE Custom Styles](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles)

```
<?php
// Insert 'styleselect' into the $buttons array
function my_mce_buttons_2( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
// Use 'mce_buttons' for button row #1, mce_buttons_3' for button row #3
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'my_mce_buttons_2');

function my_mce_before_init_insert_formats( $init_array ) {
    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Custom UL class', // Title to show in dropdown
            'selector' => 'ul', // Element to add class to
            'classes' => 'custom-ul-class' // CSS class to add
        )
    );
    $init_array['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );
    return $init_array;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_before_init_insert_formats' );
```

In editor: first create an unnumbered list, then apply the style.

**Update after acceptance**.

If you want to append a class to all `<ul>` elements added through TinyMCE you can do it prior to inserting into or updating the database:

```
<?php
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'my_add_ul_class_on_insert');
function my_add_ul_class_on_insert( $postarr ) {
    $postarr['post_content'] = str_replace('<ul>', '<ul class="my-custom-class">', $postarr['post_content'] );
    return $postarr;
}
```

Tune `str_replace()` function `needle` if `<ul>` elements already has any attributes. Or use `preg_replace()` there.

Comment: Actually I know this, and I searched the Codex too, but I wanted to add the class automatically to the ul tag without applying a style to it.

Comment: I guess this is the only way to do it.

Comment: @Peter, see one more idea above.

Answer (score 3):

Is that really necessary? Try to modify you theme's page.php and single.php in a way it's wrapp the_content(); template tag with a div of specified class or id. This way:

```
...
<div id="post_content_from_tinymce">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
...
```

And use that id in your stylesheet:

```
#post_content_from_tinymces ul{ ... }
```

This might be enaught in most cases. Adding posibility to add custom class to UL would demand to write a tinyMCE plugin and still, you would have to click extra button to set style every time you're creating a post/page.

Comment: While this is a good idea, I also have other elements on the page that will have ul tags (shortcodes...) and my issue is that I'm using ::before pseudo element on the ul tags and I don't want to overwrite this styling every time I use a ul tag.

Comment: Than you can append class to your shotcode ul and set it another css